# How can I pull hashtags out of a text column?

Tags: excel, tags, vlookup, identify

I have an Excel sheet in which there is a "description" column. The values in this column often contain anywhere from 0-3 tags, all starting with the # symbol. Is there a way to pull all of these tags out in to columns?

Perhaps just have 3 blank columns called hashtag 1, 2, 3 and pull them in to each column.

It isn't even important that it remove them from the description column while pulling them out.

Example of descriptions:

```
"#0034 #lost client lost file"            - pull out 0034    and   lost  
"worker has bad quality #SusanB #quality" - pull out SusanB  and   quality  
"#0840 client complaint"                  - pull out 0840  
"lots of ipsum"                           - pull out       nothing
```

Comment: @pnuts Simple, but definitely not a full solution. Ty

Comment: Whats your goal with this? The Main reason it wasn't a full solution was because I ended up with lots of columns that had the description left after the tag. so for "#0888 #jessej file lost" Becomes ColA: 0888 ColB: Jessej file lost. this is instead of a colC for "file lost" which is the description. @pnuts

Answer (score 2):

Lets say Column A is Description column, and in A2 you have the first cell with hashtags
In B2 enter:

```
=MID(A2;(FIND("#";A2))+1;(FIND(" ";MID(A2;(FIND("#";A2))+1;LEN(A2)-(FIND("#";A2))))+(FIND("#";A2)))-(FIND("#";A2))-1)
```

In C2 enter:

```
=MID(A2;(FIND("#";MID(A2;(FIND("#";A2))+1;LEN(A2)-(FIND("#";A2))))+(FIND("#";A2)))+1;(FIND(" ";MID(A2;(FIND("#";MID(A2;(FIND("#";A2))+1;LEN(A2)-(FIND("#";A2))))+(FIND("#";A2)))+1;LEN(A2)-(FIND("#";MID(A2;(FIND("#";A2))+1;LEN(A2)-(FIND("#";A2))))+(FIND("#";A2)))))+(FIND("#";MID(A2;(FIND("#";A2))+1;LEN(A2)-(FIND("#";A2))))+(FIND("#";A2))))-(FIND("#";MID(A2;(FIND("#";A2))+1;LEN(A2)-(FIND("#";A2))))+(FIND("#";A2)))-1)
```

In D2 enter:

```
=MID(A2;(FIND("#";MID(A2;(FIND("#";MID(A2;(FIND("#";A2))+1;LEN(A2)-(FIND("#";A2))))+(FIND("#";A2)))+1;LEN(A2)-(FIND("#";MID(A2;(FIND("#";A2))+1;LEN(A2)-(FIND("#";A2))))+(FIND("#";A2)))))+(FIND("#";MID(A2;(FIND("#";A2))+1;LEN(A2)-(FIND("#";A2))))+(FIND("#";A2))))+1;(FIND(" ";MID(A2;(FIND("#";MID(A2;(FIND("#";MID(A2;(FIND("#";A2))+1;LEN(A2)-(FIND("#";A2))))+(FIND("#";A2)))+1;LEN(A2)-(FIND("#";MID(A2;(FIND("#";A2))+1;LEN(A2)-(FIND("#";A2))))+(FIND("#";A2)))))+(FIND("#";MID(A2;(FIND("#";A2))+1;LEN(A2)-(FIND("#";A2))))+(FIND("#";A2))))+1;LEN(A2)-(FIND("#";MID(A2;(FIND("#";MID(A2;(FIND("#";A2))+1;LEN(A2)-(FIND("#";A2))))+(FIND("#";A2)))+1;LEN(A2)-(FIND("#";MID(A2;(FIND("#";A2))+1;LEN(A2)-(FIND("#";A2))))+(FIND("#";A2)))))+(FIND("#";MID(A2;(FIND("#";A2))+1;LEN(A2)-(FIND("#";A2))))+(FIND("#";A2))))))+(FIND("#";MID(A2;(FIND("#";MID(A2;(FIND("#";A2))+1;LEN(A2)-(FIND("#";A2))))+(FIND("#";A2)))+1;LEN(A2)-(FIND("#";MID(A2;(FIND("#";A2))+1;LEN(A2)-(FIND("#";A2))))+(FIND("#";A2)))))+(FIND("#";MID(A2;(FIND("#";A2))+1;LEN(A2)-(FIND("#";A2))))+(FIND("#";A2)))))-(FIND("#";MID(A2;(FIND("#";MID(A2;(FIND("#";A2))+1;LEN(A2)-(FIND("#";A2))))+(FIND("#";A2)))+1;LEN(A2)-(FIND("#";MID(A2;(FIND("#";A2))+1;LEN(A2)-(FIND("#";A2))))+(FIND("#";A2)))))+(FIND("#";MID(A2;(FIND("#";A2))+1;LEN(A2)-(FIND("#";A2))))+(FIND("#";A2))))-1)
```

Comment: These are probably very good, but they are not working. I paste them in and am getting a message that there is an error in the formula. I cannot follow it easily enough to find the issue.

Comment: yeah, IFERROR... you're right, to get rid of error text in cells, I don't use it too often, because I don't mind having info about input or output errors...

Answer (score 1):

I'm fond of an extension that can let you use REGEX in Excel ...

Without this :

1) find the position of the separator character (# ?) in your string with FIND()

2) then use LEFT(), MID() and RIGHT() to explode your string into 3 columns

3) you can delete the # using MID() instead of LEFT() and RIGHT()

--

It would be something like this for the first tag with the # :

=LEFT(A1,FIND("#",A1)-1)

--

Hope this will help !

Comment: I am having trouble getting this to work. There is potential, but I am getting all the stuff to the left of the # rather than the right. When I use the right() function, I am getting stuff from the left of the tag as well as x characters to the right.

Answer (score 0):

This can always be done using regular expression.

In VBE, write following function in a module:

```
Function getHashTags(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim regEx As RegExp
    Set regEx = New RegExp
    regEx.Pattern = "#\w*\b"
    regEx.IgnoreCase = True
    regEx.Global = True
    Set myMatches = regEx.Execute(rng.Value)
    Dim arr(1 To 1, 1 To 3) As Variant
    For i = 1 To 3
        If i > myMatches.Count Then
            arr(1, i) = ""
        Else
            arr(1, i) = Replace(myMatches(i - 1), "#", "")
        End If
    Next i
    getHashTags = arr
End Function
```

Now, let's suppose Column A is the Description column, and in cell A2 you have the first cell with hash tags.

In cell B2 enter this:

```
=getHashTags(B$2)
```

Now select the cells B2, C2, D2, Press <kbd>F2</kbd> and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>. This will populate the variant return from the function `getHashTags` to the selected cells.

I hope this helps.

PS: And, yes for this to work you also need to give reference to **Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5** library.